# Add space in math mode

Tags: macros, spacing

I would like to add automatically a small space after one macro content inside a math formula.

The problem I have is that this space must be gobbled if it is at the end of the formula.

What is is the good concept to use to do that kind of stuff ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\param[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

xxxxx$\param{a} x^2 + \param{b} x + \param{c}$xxxx

xxxxx$\param{a}\,x^2 + \param{b}\, x + \param{c}$xxxx

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newcommand\param[1]{\mathop{\mathbf{{}#1}}}

\begin{document}

xxxxx$\param{a} x^2 + \param{b} x + \param{c}$xxxx

xxxxx$\param{a}\,x^2 + \param{b}\, x + \param{c}$xxxx

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can I fand the code used by `\mathop` ?

Comment: the texbook (or tex-by-topic I guess) it is a tex primitive: the basis of all commands like `\log` or `\sin` or amsmath `\operatorname` @projetmbc

Comment: This not works. See the vertical position of the b for example.

Comment: @projetmbc oops sorry see update (you need a correction so that single-letter operators are not vertically centred, which is needed for \sum etc)

Comment: Why does the addition of {} make things work ?

Comment: @projetmbc that is essentially the definition of `\operatorname` in amsmath but with `mathrm` not `mathbf`  it just makes sure the content is never a single letter

Comment: Thanks for all.